# How to get users in voice channel without cache in DiscordJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get all users connected to a voice channel on my server. When someone talks to a bot in `#general`, I want to get the users inside `Voice Channel 1`.

I'm using Node 17 and DiscordJS 13.

This is my code:

```js
message.guild.channels
  .fetch(channelID, { cache: false, force: true })
  .then((channels) => {
    console.log(channels.members);
  });
```

Also, I tried this one:

```js
let voiceChannel = client.guilds.cache
  .get(process.env.DISCORDJS_GUILD_ID)
  .channels.cache.get(process.env.DISCORDJS_CHANNEL_ID);
let membersInChannel = voiceChannel.members;
console.log(membersInChannel);
```

But, it always returns the voice channel users that joined when I start the node app. If someone leaves the voice channel, it keeps showing him in the `console.log` when I say something to the bot in `#general`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69833058/8037905) and it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Although I added `{ force: true }` as the option in `fetch`, it always showed the same number of members when I started the app, ignoring the ones who joined/left the channel.

Enabling the [`GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) solved this. So don't forget to add it to your `client`:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
  ],
});
```