# How do I get the user count of a voice by channel id? Discordjs v.13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I get the user count of a voice by channel id? I'm using Discordjs v.13.

Here's my current code:

```js
async function usercount(channelId) {
  try {
    let voiceChannel = Client.guilds.cache
      .get('guildId')
      .channels.cache.get(channelId);
    let membersInChannel = voiceChannel.members.size;
    console.log(membersInChannel);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Error while performing usercount');
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's `Client`?

Comment: `Client` is the Discordjs Client.
I want to resolve the amount of member connect to a specific voice channel with the ID of the voice channel, but I don't get any value whatsoever from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of members by [fetching the voice channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) by its ID and grabbing its [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) property. You'll probably need to use the [`{ force: true }` option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/BaseFetchOptions) to skip the cache check and request the API. This way, when someone leaves/joins the channel, the number will still be accurate.

Notice that you will either need a guild ID or a guild to which the voice channel belongs.

```js
async function userCount(guildId, channelId) {
  try {
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
    let voiceChannel = await guild.channels.fetch(channelId, { force: true });

    return voiceChannel.members?.size;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Error while performing usercount');
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And here is an example how to use this. Here, I'm passing down the `message.guild.id` as the guild ID, and the first argument as the channel ID.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
  ],
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const channelId = args[0];

  message.reply(
    `There are ${await userCount(
      message.guild.id,
      channelId,
    )} members in the voice channel _"${
      message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId).name
    }"_`,
  );
});
```

[image]

**Important:** Don't forget that you'll need to [enable the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72897773/6126373). Without that the number of connected members won't change.

Comment: Is it possible to use the voice state instead of the guild object because I have trouble to using the client even though I declared the intents. Guild is always undefined.

Comment: `VoiceStates` do have a [`guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=guild) property, so you can also use that. You could replace `function userCount(guildId, channelId)` with `function userCount(voiceState, channelId)` and `let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);` with `let {guild} = voiceState;`. This way, you can pass the voice state as the first argument.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible getting the current number of users in a voice channel by channel ID. The ID is just like the name of the channel. For your bot to identify the channel and to f.E. change the name of the channel. However you wont be able to get the currently connected users of the channel.

Or did I missunderstand something? Hope this helps

Comment: I thought there is a way to e.g. request voice state objects (users) of a channel with the channel ID

Comment: Not possible with what I know... :(. Would indeed be a handy feature

Comment: That's incorrect. Why do you think you can't get the connected users by a channel ID?